# John the Ripper add special characters

Tags: john-the-ripper

I have been trying to do this for hours and can´t really figure this out.

How can I pass only this range of signs to John the Ripper?

./john hashes  --mask=Pepito[1234567890!"·$%&/()=|@#~€]--min-length=9 --max-length=21

I basically know half of the password and know the variation will be between those characters but since it seems there are some characters used for different commands JtR is unable to add them to the list.

I also tried \ before the signs but didn't manage Pepito[1234567890!"\·$%&/()=|@#~\€]

Comment: I let you here a few links to different documentation that I think it will help you. After the reading, if you still having trouble I will try to solve your question. https://gracefulsecurity.com/custom-rules-for-john-the-ripper/   https://gracefulsecurity.com/custom-rules-for-john-the-ripper-examples/ https://github.com/openwall/john/issues/824                          https://www.openwall.com/john/doc/RULES.shtml

Comment: The search term you are looking for is "character set". There are lots of tutorials and john has documentation on this.